# Neo4J Rest Javascript wrapper

Tags: javascript, database, graph, wrapper, rest

As a toy project, I started evaluating the Neo4J graph database and its Rest interface. I'm trying to write a simple graph visualization in JavaScript. In daily business I'm a Java developer and maybe that's the reason why I'm not that happy with my current approach. In Java I would have written a `Neo4J` class, with inner (data) classes for `Node` and `Relation` as their `id` is tightly couple to the server (`http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0`). Maybe they even would get a common parent class.

In JavaScript I don't get away from my object oriented mind. I need some ideas in relation to JavaScript best practice.

```
function Neo4J(server) {
    this.server = server;
}

function Node(connection, response) {
    this.id = connection.sanitizeId(response['self']);
    this.data = response['data'];
}

function Relation(connection, response) {
    this.id = connection.sanitizeId(response['self']);
    this.start = connection.sanitizeId(response['start']);
    this.end = connection.sanitizeId(response['end']);
    this.type = response['type'];
}

Neo4J.prototype = {
    sanitizeId: function (id) {
        return id.replace(this.server, "");
    },

    query: function (query, success) {
        return post(this.server + "/cypher", {"query": query, "params": {} }, success);
    },

    getAllNodes: function (callback) {
        var connection = this;
        this.query("MATCH n RETURN n", function (nodes) {
            $.each(nodes['data'], function (i, val) {
                callback(new Node(connection, val[0]));
            });
        });
    },

    getAllRelations: function (callback) {
        var connection = this;
        this.query("START r=rel(*) RETURN r", function (nodes) {
            $.each(nodes['data'], function (i, val) {
                callback(new Relation(connection, val[0]));
            });
        });
    },

    getNode: function (id, callback) {
        var connection = this;
        get(this.server + id + "/properties", function (data) {
            if (data == null) data = {data: {}};
            else data = {data: data};
            data['self'] = id;
            callback(new Node(connection, data));
        });
    },

    createNode: function (callback) {
        var connection = this;
        post(this.server + '/node', null, function (data) {
            callback(new Node(connection, data));
        });
    },

    setNodeProperty: function (node, key, value, callback) {
        put(this.server + node.id + '/properties/' + key, '"'+value+'"', function (data) {
            node.data[key] = value;
            callback(node);
        });
    },

    createRelation: function (start, target, type, callback) {
        var connection = this;
        post(this.server + start + '/relationships', {to: this.server + target, type: type}, function (data) {
            callback(new Relation(connection, data));
        });
    }

}
```

The `post()` and  `put()` are just ajax calls to the Neo4J server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question,

The most striking thing is your repeated use of this pattern:

```
connection.sanitizeId(response['xxx']);
```

I dont believe `sanitizeId` should be a function of `connection`. Also, `response` is not a good name because it often is part of a response from the query and not the actual response. And, it is suggested that `response.xxx` makes more sense than `response['xxx']`. To that end, I feel that `sanitizeId` should be part of the `response` or data. Also, I would be tempted to call it simply `sanitize`.

```
function addSanitizer( data , server){
  data.sanitize = function( propertyName ){
    return this[propertyName].replace( server , "" );
  }
  return data;
}
```

Then you could do

```
function Node(response) {
    this.id   = response.sanitize( 'self' );
    this.data = response.data;
}
```

Or, if you agree that response might be misleading

```
function Node(node) {
    this.id   = node.sanitize( 'self' );
    this.data = node.data;  
}
```

`Node` with be called like this:

```
getNode: function (id, callback) {
    var connection = this;
    get(this.server + id + "/properties", function (data) {
        if (data == null) data = {data: {}};
        else data = {data: data};
        data['self'] = id;
        callback(new Node(this.addSanitizer( data, this.server ), data));
    });
},
```

From a style point:

- You are skipping new lines on your if statements: `if (data == null) data = {data: {}};`, dont do that
- Your code stretches quite a bit horizontally, but not too bad, feel free to to split up some of your longer lines into something more readable, this :

  ```
  createRelation: function (start, target, type, callback) {
      var connection = this;
      post(this.server + start + '/relationships', {to: this.server + target, type: type}, function (data) {
          callback(new Relation(connection, data));
      });
  }
  ```

  could be

  ```
  createRelation: function (start, target, type, callback) {
      var connection = this,
          data = {to: this.server + target, type: type};
      post(this.server + start + '/relationships', data , function (data){
          callback(new Relation(connection, data));
      });
  }
  ```

The code looks all in all fine to me. For a Java developer you did good :P

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I guess the if is more a religious discussion. If I add a line break, I also have to add braces and so I get 3-4 lines. Also a line length of 160 character is only an issue in web representation. But you are right, a final refactoring is missing anyway.

Comment: I like the idea of the sanitizer, but have the feeling that this is a kind of over-engineered if I only need it for exactly one field? In my OO-mind I think the Neo4J(Server) class should be responsible for transforming an absolute server specific id to a relative id (and vice versa)? I really need to get used to bind this to the actual data. Btw. the `response` is called `response` because it is exactly the ajax rest response. In java this would be a constructor to create a `Node` from a `JsonResponse`.